# ValueError: Negative dimension size caused by subtracting 35 from 15 for 'MaxPool_2'

Tags: keras, python-3.5

I am trying to implement the cnn keras model with pretrained word embeddings from the official example, but with my own custom dataset. Here is the url:
https://github.com/fchollet/keras/blob/master/examples/pretrained_word_embeddings.py
I am using Keras 1.2.0 with Tensorflow 1.2.1.

I get an error on lines 132-134. After searching online, all the posts pointed out to the ordering. I tried the suggestions for both tf and th, but still it didnt work.

```
from keras import backend as K
K.set_image_dim_ordering('tf')
```

Any ideas?

```
  File "/home/usr/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/ops.py", line 2508, in create_op
    set_shapes_for_outputs(ret)
  File "/home/usr/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/ops.py", line 1873, in set_shapes_for_outputs
    shapes = shape_func(op)
  File "/home/usr/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/ops.py", line 1823, in call_with_requiring
    return call_cpp_shape_fn(op, require_shape_fn=True)
  File "/home/usr/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/common_shapes.py", line 610, in call_cpp_shape_fn
    debug_python_shape_fn, require_shape_fn)
  File "/home/usr/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/common_shapes.py", line 676, in _call_cpp_shape_fn_impl
    raise ValueError(err.message)
ValueError: Negative dimension size caused by subtracting 35 from 15 for 'MaxPool_2' (op: 'MaxPool') with input shapes: [?,15,1,128].
```

Comment: What's your input sequence length?

Comment: @Yu-Yang from sequence_input = Input(shape=(MAX_SEQUENCE_LENGTH,), dtype='int32') it prints shape = (?,500)

Comment: It was too small for my data. Thanks you @Yu-Yang